# write rewriterule for just index.php?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

How can write rewriterule to redirect just:

http://example.com/index.php   to https://example.com/index.php

And anything else stays the same

ex:
http://example.com/index.php?a=2&lang=English remains as it is http://example.com/index.php?a=2&lang=English

Answer (score 1):

Check with [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) if `QUERY_STRING` is empty and if `HTTPS` is "off" before redirecting the client with a [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([^?]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

Comment: but not work probable

Comment: `THE_REQUEST` is the wrong variable, use the one I've mentioned. Also `SERVER_NAME` should be `HTTP_HOST`.